# decimal value parameter in oci_bind_by_name for calling an Oracle stored procedure

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Reading

[php oci_bind_by_name float to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862764/php-oci-bind-by-name-float-to-numeric)

I cannot use a decimal value in a $p6 variable like that :

```
$lmd  = "CALL ajoute_vol(:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,TO_DATE(:p5,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),:p6,:p7)"; 
...
$pduree = round(1.2/24,2); // 1h12 min 
...
print "</p>duree : ". $pduree;
oci_bind_by_name($etat, ':p6', $pduree,-1, SQLT_NUM);
...
print "</p>duree : ". $pduree;
oci_execute ($etat, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);   // COMMIT est dans la procédure
...
```

The result is 1/ $pduree seems to be set to 0 but in the call this not a zero passing.

```
duree : 0.05
duree : 0
```

If I set :p6 to 0 in the call it works (but I want pass a decimal value instead).

```
$lmd  = "CALL ajoute_vol(:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,TO_DATE(:p5,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),0,:p7)";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
oci_bind_by_name($etat, ':p6', $pduree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem : Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-01722
A solution is to include the calculus in the prepare statement :

```
"CALL ajoute_vol(:p1,:p2,:p3,:p4,TO_DATE(:p5,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), ROUND((:p6+:p7/100)/24,2), :p8)"
```